# numpy change array values when mask is one

Tags: python, numpy

i'm new to numpy and i'm running into trouble.

I've got two numpy arrays, img and thr:

```
>>>img.shape
(2448, 3264, 3)
>>>thr.shape
(2448, 3264)
```

And i want to do something like this: set `img[x,y] = [255,255,255]` only when `thr[x,y] is not 0`

I tried iterating over the array and do it myself but it takes a long time, so i really need the C underneath numpy. I also took a look to masked arrays but i didn't understand how to use them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [NumPy assignment to an indexed array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays):

```
img[thr != 0] = [255,255,255]
```