# How to Mask an image using Numpy/OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have an image I load with:

```
im = cv2.imread(filename)
```

I want to keep data that is in the center of the image.  I created a circle as a mask of the area I want to keep.

I created the circle with:

```
height,width,depth = im.shape
circle = np.zeros((height,width))
cv2.circle(circle,(width/2,height/2),280,1,thickness=-1)
```

How can I mask out the data outside of the circle from the original image?

```
masked_data = im * circle
```

does not work.

Comment: do you want to crop circle ?

Comment: Yes. I want to keep everything within the circle.

Comment: So is this just a question of numpy broadcasting?

Answer (score 23):

Use `cv2.bitwise_and` and pass the circle as mask.

```
im = cv2.imread(filename)
height,width,depth = im.shape
circle_img = np.zeros((height,width), np.uint8)
cv2.circle(circle_img,(width/2,height/2),280,1,thickness=-1)

masked_data = cv2.bitwise_and(im, im, mask=circle_img)

cv2.imshow("masked", masked_data)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Froyo. The color parameter has to be 255 for me to work. So the code should be`cv2.circle(circle_img,(width/2,height/2),280,255,thickness=-1)`

Comment: `(width/2,height/2)` gives the position of the circle (hopefully the center) on the image while `280` is the size (hopefully the radius) of the circle. Does this positioning directly translate to the `x,y` cordinate positioning?

Comment: width and height are backwards in np.zeros, and the circle fill color should be 255

Answer (score 5):

`circle` is just a 2D array with `1.0`s and `0.0`s. Numpy needs help to understand what you want to do with the third dimension of your `im` so you must give it an extra axis and then your line would work.

```
masked_data = im * circle[..., np.newaxis]
```

But note that the masking is simply setting the color to `(0, 0, 0)` for things outside the circle according to your code if the image lacks an alpha-channel.

However you have another potential problem: `circle` will be of the default data-type (which probably will be `float64` or `float32`. That's not good for your image, so you should change the line where you create `circle` to

```
circle = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=im.dtype)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case if you want to have a circular image you must write a new algorithm and first you must be able to access to the coordinates of the pixels. Then you can simply compare pixels that are not within the scope of that circle or not and replace them with some value (or NULL if it's accepted with your image format criteria).

Here is an example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
im = cv2.imread('sss.png')


def facechop(im):

 height,width,depth = im.shape
 #circle = np.zeros((height,width))
 #print circle
 x=width/2
 y=height/2
 circle=cv2.circle(im,(width/2,height/2),180,1,thickness=1)
 #newcameramtx, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(im,10,(w,h),1,(w,h))
 cv2.rectangle(im,(x-180,y-180),(x+180,y+180),(0,0,255),2)
 crop_img = im[y-180:y+180,x-180:x+180]
 lastim=np.equal(crop_img,circle)
 #dd=np.logical_and(crop_img,circle)

 for i in range(len(last_im)) :
     if last_im[i].all()==False:
         crop_img[i]=[0,0,0]


 cv2.imshow('im',crop_img)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    facechop(im)
    while(True):
        key = cv2.waitKey(20)
        if key in [27, ord('Q'), ord('q')]:
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [NumPy assignment to an indexed array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays):

```
im[circle == 0] = [0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: This is a community wiki for [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13659401/2291710) answered by @unutbu.