# RGB average of circles

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm using OpenCV and PIL in Python. I have 96 circles detected with their **center** **coordinates** and **radios**. I need the average RGB from each circles.

Each circle has 6000 pixels, so I thinks iterate one to one it is not efficient.

How can I extract the average RGB from each circle?
I am ready to use any other library if it suits my use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I get it, this is the solution:

```
circle_img = np.zeros((color_img.shape[0],color_img.shape[1]), np.uint8) #Creamos mascara (matriz de ceros) del tamano de la imagen original
cv2.circle(circle_img,(x_center,y_center),radio,(255,255,255),-1) #Pintamos los circulos en la mascara
datos_rgb = cv2.mean(color_img, mask=circle_img)[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use openCV library

- load your image
- create masks for the circles ([How to Mask an image using Numpy/OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074488/how-to-mask-an-image-using-numpy-opencv))
- compute mean color for each circle ([mean_val = cv2.mean(im,mask = mask)](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#Scalar%20mean(InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20mask)))

All of these steps is supported by openCV.

Comment: Thanks a lot but it does not work, I'm getting this error:
error: (-215) (mask.type() == CV_8UC1 || mask.type() == CV_8SC1) in function binary_op
And my code is:
mask = np.zeros(color_img.shape, np.uint8)
cv2.circle(mask,(key[0][0],key[0][1]),radio_medio,255,thickness=-1)
masked_data = cv2.bitwise_and(color_img, color_img, mask=mask)
mean = cv2.mean(color_img, mask=masked_data)
print(mean)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too specific, but if you are using keypoints (by the way, this is just a "pretty" version from @Jota's answer):

```
def average_keypoint_value(canvas,keypoints):
    average_value = []
    if canvas.ndim == 2:
        nchannels = 1
    elif canvas.ndim > 2:
        nchannels = canvas.shape[-1]
    for keypoint in keypoints:
        circle_x =      int(keypoint.pt[0])
        circle_y =      int(keypoint.pt[1])
        circle_radius=  int(keypoint.size/2)
        #copypasta from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43170927/2594947
        circle_img = np.zeros((canvas.shape[:2]), np.uint8)
        cv2.circle(circle_img,(circle_x,circle_y),circle_radius,(255,255,255),-1)
        datos_rgb = cv2.mean(canvas, mask=circle_img)
        average_value.append(datos_rgb[:nchannels])
    return(average_value)
```

Just leaving it here in case someone else wants a function for this.