# How do I find image location within document of multiple images and texts using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a document that contains text and images (it's in png format) and a source image which is included in the document (source image is bigger and in better quality).
I would like to find the location (coordinates) of source image in the document.

What makes the process complicated is that the source image in the document might be unevenly scaled (eg.: more vertically than horizontally), a bit cropped (so it's smaller than source image) and slighty modified version of source image (eg.: has rounded edges).

[image]

I've tried the [OpenCV template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) but with mediocre results - it doesn't handle well uneven scaling.

Is there a way to do it using python and openCV? Or another way?

Comment: Extract every image from your text document using (outer) contours with large areas. Get the dimensions and scale one image to match the size of the other. Then do a difference between the two or use template matching to find the match score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Convert the color image to gray, do some threshold, and find contours: [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

2) Find the bounding box for contours [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html)

3) Most likely that your image will have some properties for you to pick from the list generated in step 2. For example, width and height are greater than a minimum value.

4) Now create a mask with the chosen bounding box [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074488/how-to-mask-an-image-using-numpy-opencv)

5) Now compare histogram distribution between mask region and your image using chi-square distance. A distance less than 1 implies a perfect match. [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/12/01/complete-guide-building-image-search-engine-python-opencv/)

6) The bounding box gives the (x,y) coordinates, which you are looking for.